# css of bootstrap 3 in django not working as expected

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to use tabbable divs in my django app. The toggle seem to work as expected, the content does show when the next tab is clicked.

But the CSS doesn't seem to be working. When I click on tab2, the focus still is in tab 1. On tab 2, it only grays out the button and when I click on other parts of the page the gray out disappears and even if tab2 details are shown, the focus is on tab 1.

[image: tabbable screenshot]

Just to add here are my load scripts for the page

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
```

On load of the page, I inspected the sources in chrome dev tools. In the sources section, I can see that jquery and bootstrap are loaded.

[image: sources]

Comment: Did you add dependencies for bootstrap 3? It depends on jquery for most of the widgets that require javascript animations. If so first add jquery and then add bootstrap since it has to be loaded before bootstrap

Comment: nope I didn't know they were required thanks for pointing this out. what I did was installed  this package django_static_jquery and declared in installed apps. also, called load static and pointed to static directory as declared here. https://pypi.org/project/django-static-jquery/ but still doesnt work. or is this what I need to do?

Comment: also I forgot, I have this declared in my base.html. <script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work. I thought the libraries were not being loaded properly. In a way, because of the way the libraries are imported, they don't seem to work properly.

here's how it looks like at the top of my template

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% static 'static_jquery/js/jquery.js' %}

{% block content %}

    {% load bootstrap3 %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript %}
```

What it made work for me was that the bootstrap related libraries must be placed inside the block content. Before, it is placed up top after the load static statements.

And also I had to remove hardcoded script tags at the bottom of my template, then it worked. I had these removed

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Other things that I did was install django_static_jquery, then performed collectstatic

Answer (score 3):

If your CSS is not working try collecting static files :

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: after adding jquery library I did this. unfortunately its still the same.